# SBT doesn't find file in local maven repository although it's there

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm having problems with a maven dependency which is in my local respository.

SBT can't find it. Already set log level to debug, but not getting anything new.

The files are in the repository. I copy paste paths from the console to file explorer and they are there.

The output:

```
[debug]          trying file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0.0/naggati-2.0.0.pom

[debug]                 tried file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0.0/naggati-2.0.0.pom

[debug]         Local Maven Repository: resource not reachable for com/twitter#naggati;2.0.0: res=file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0
.0/naggati-2.0.0.pom

[debug]          trying file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0.0/naggati-2.0.0.jar

[debug]                 tried file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0.0/naggati-2.0.0.jar

[debug]         Local Maven Repository: resource not reachable for com/twitter#naggati;2.0.0: res=file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository/com/twitter/naggati/2.0
.0/naggati-2.0.0.jar

[debug]         Local Maven Repository: no ivy file nor artifact found for com.twitter#naggati;2.0.0
```

**Edit: I added the path using scala file in project/build** like described in http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement

"sbt can search your local Maven repository if you add it as a repository:"

```
val mavenLocal = "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository"
```

That made sbt look in the local repository. Before it didn't.

So the scala file looks like this:

```
import sbt._

class Foo(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {

val mavenLocal = "Local Maven Repository" at "file://c:/Users/userz/.m2/repository"

}
```

(I hardcoded Path.userHome to exclude possible error reason. As expected it didn't change anything).

Comment: You have to add the local maven repo to your build.sbt

Comment: The repository is added, otherwise the script would not look there for the files.

Comment: How is the line that tells sbt to look for your dependency? If you have something like ... -> default, remove default from there.

Comment: Actually I'm not using build.sbt. I'm using a scala file like described in http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement. Edited my post with more details.

Comment: ixx: That's SBT 0.7.x, and it's the legacy version. You should update to [SBT 0.11.x])https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), if possible.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need three slashes after the `file:` specifier. This is because between the second and third slash, you have an optional hostname. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) has a good explanation of `file:` URL's

You're having a problem because the typical pattern of `"file://"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository"` assumes a Unix filesystem, where the path begins with a `/`, contains no `:`, and usually contains no spaces.

To have a non-hardcoded path that works on both Windows and Linux/Unix, use:

```
"Local Maven" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"
```

Comment: not with projects defined and adding to the project doesn't work either

Answer (score 161):

Just add this line in the build.scala or build.sbt file

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Comment: Which sbt is that? I used it with 0.13.11 and it works just fine.

Comment: `resolvers in Global := Resolver.mavenLocal` works for me.

Comment: OMG I've searched an hour for this perfect solution! Thx

Comment: @retronym, I think you meant "resolvers in Global += Resolver.mavenLocal"

Comment: For SBT 1.3.x it's `ThisBuild / resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`

Answer (score 21):

To get this to work for newer versions of sbt, add the following to build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository"
```

Comment: No matter what I do I still get this error when doing sbt compile:
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.sanoma.cda#maxmind-geoip2-scala_2.11;1.3.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sanoma.cda#maxmind-geoip2-scala_2.11;1.3.2: not found

Comment: I used `resolvers in Global += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://" + Path.userHome + "/.m2/repository"`

Answer (score 3):

Watch out when you have a project defined, you'll need to include the resolver in the settings. Global resolver will not be identified.

Example:

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
    name := "Core",
    libraryDependencies := coreDependencies
  )
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, though it may have something to do with projects

Comment: Thanks Dyin, It worked.
Added resolver to commonSettings, now all defined projects can look into local maven repo for dependencies.