# Local File Resolution against local Maven repository

Tags: maven, sbt, resolver

I have put a local repo resolver line into the build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Local Repo" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository"
```

Also I installed a file locally using mvn install

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file  -Dfile=c:\shared\py4j-0.8.1.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.py4j  -DartifactId=py4j -Dversion=0.7 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Here we can see the file was installed into the local repo:

```
C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf>dir C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.7\py4j-0.7.pom

 Directory of C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.7

05/13/2014  12:52 PM               457 py4j-0.7.pom
```

But during the build process the file can not be found:

```
[warn]  module not found: net.sf.py4j#py4j;0.7
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\local\net.sf.py4j\py4j\0.7\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.pom
[warn] ==== Apache repo: tried
[warn]   https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.pom
[warn] ==== Cloudera repo: tried
[warn]   https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/org/apache/kafka/kafka/0.7.2-spark/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.pom
[warn] ==== Local Repo: tried
[warn]   file://C:/Users/S80035683/.m2/repository/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.pom
```

Note in particular the last line:

file://C:/Users/S80035683/.m2/repository/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.pom

That is the same path that we installed to earlier - i.e **the file does exist**

```
C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf>dir C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.7\py4j-0.7.pom

 Directory of C:\Users\S80035683\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.7

05/13/2014  12:52 PM               457 py4j-0.7.pom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Windows-specific. There is another question that has helpful pointers on how to resolve.

[SBT doesn't find file in local maven repository although it's there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773319/sbt-doesnt-find-file-in-local-maven-repository-although-its-there)

Specifically one of the following three means to resolve may be used:

```
file:// needs to be file:///
```

(that is specific to windows..)

OR:  better /portable solutions:

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

OR

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository"
```