# sbt local m2 repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I have added `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal` the the plugins.sbt file However sbt only seems to resolve `~/.ivi` and not `~/.m2` repository. How can I change that?

I tried this as well but it did not seem to work

resolvers += "Local m2y" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"

## edit

the error message
[image]
but the file is there
[image]

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773319/sbt-doesnt-find-file-in-local-maven-repository-although-its-there?rq=1 and tried three slashes after `file:`

Comment: I love the screenshots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to do the trick. I updated the post to reflect the error mesage / proof that the file is there in the m2 folder. Strangely the MavenLocal resolver works just fine on my mac - but apparently not on linux.

Comment: It is possible that You need to use different variables to extract user home.

Comment: Doesn't work, in fact, this line won't be parsed at all in the latest sbt

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `repositories` file, you can add `maven-local` alongwith `local`.
Reference -> https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html#3.+Repositories+Section